# React / JS how to detect if component is being clicked but not anything inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not sure if this problem matches React or vanilla JS.

but if I have this code:

```
<div>
    <span>Test</Span>
</div>
```

I want to detect if someone clicked on the div element, but not on the span element or anything else inside the div.

how can it be done?

An example to a div with reference ( React feature ):

```
<div ref={this.refEl}>
     <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

and above that code, inside the `render` I could do:

`this.refElement = React.createRef();`

And now I have a reference to that element, but now how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can compare `event.currentTarget` and `event.target`. When they are equal, the element with the event listener was clicked. When they are NOT equal, a child was clicked.

Here's a full example:

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1')
const section = document.querySelector('section')

section.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget === event.target) {
    h1.innerText = 'You clicked the section'
  } else {
    h1.innerText = `You clicked the ${event.target.tagName.toLowerCase()} inside the section`
  }
})
```

```css
section {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 20px;
}
section,
article,
section h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px;
}
article {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
}
section h1 {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Try clicking the colored boxes...</h1>

<section>
  Section
  <article>
    Article
    <h1>Heading</h1>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! but if I use `ref` feature of React, I don't have access to `currentTarget` and `target`, what is the alternative?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Could you update your question with some of your code?

Comment: Yeah I changed the answer with an example

Comment: Ah you have a ref for the `div`? You won't need to use that here. Just add an `onClick` listener to the `div` and compare the target properties like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this in a React app then your `onClick` handler should use `event.stopPropagation()` when you don't want the click to be registered by elements that aren't targetted.

Here's an example of a React component using this in action.

```
import React from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
  function handleDivClick() {
    console.log('div clicked')
  }

  function handleSpanClick(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    console.log('span clicked')
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleDivClick}>
      <span onClick={handleSpanClick}>
        Content
      </span>
    </div>

  )
}
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want to disable anything inside, no side-effects, and there are many components but this span, so I think an inner onClick might be over-kill?